# Rest api endpoint with basic auth results 401 in protractor

Tags: angular, protractor

I have the below code snippet in protractor e2e. Calling the REST API endpoint with basic auth results in "HTTP 401 unauthorized."

```
import {HttpClient, HttpXhrBackend, XhrFactory, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import { XMLHttpRequest} from 'xmlhttprequest';

export class BrowserXhr implements XhrFactory {
  constructor() {}
  build(): any {
    return <any > (new XMLHttpRequest());
  }
}

describe('test: ', () => {
  const http: HttpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpXhrBackend(new BrowserXhr()));

  it('test', (done) => {
    let headers_object = new HttpHeaders();
    headers_object.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers_object.append('Authorization', 'Basic my_auth_key');

    const httpOptions = {
      headers: headers_object
    };
    http.post('https://exp.com', {
      name: 'aa',
      i: 'aa'
    }, httpOptions).subscribe((response: any) => {
      expect(response.message).toEqual('success');
      done();
    }, (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      done.fail(error.message);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: For starters, you should probably be using node's http module not angular's. https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/https.html

Answer (score 0):

I changed http headers as below, worked for me.
`const headersObject = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json', Authorization: 'Basic my_auth_key'});`